# selecting distinct members in a class with constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Named as "Patients" which looks like this

> ```
> > PatientName      DateOftest    Eye     L1    L2    L3    L4     L5
> >     Mike         17-02-2009     L      23    25    40    32     30
> >     Mike         17-02-2009     R      25    30    34    35     24
> >     Ryan         18-03-2012     R      12    18    27    39     40
> >     Bill         08-03-2006     L      20    24    30    24     25
> >     Bill         08-03-2006     R      18    25    27    30     24   
> >     Chan         03-08-2009     L      18    21    28    35     12
> ```

No, I have to select * from the patients where the patient have only one (Either left eye record or right eye record tests).. Result would be

> ```
> Ryan         18-03-2012     R      12    18    27    39     40
> Chan         03-08-2009     L      18    21    28    35     12
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Patients
WHERE PatientName IN(SELECT PatientName 
                     FROM Patients
                     GROUP BY PatientName 
                     HAVING COUNT(*) = 1);
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02a0e/1)

This will give you:

```
| PATIENTNAME | DATEOFTEST | EYE | L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 | L5 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|        Ryan | 18-03-2012 |   R | 12 | 18 | 27 | 39 | 40 |
|        Chan | 03-08-2009 |   L | 18 | 21 | 28 | 35 | 12 |
```

Comment: My understanding is that it gives the wrong answer if a patient has correct and incorrect records. [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dcde8/1). The result should still show Chan.

Comment: @peterm Why Chan? Chan has three entries in this table. So it shouldn't be selected. The only selected name is Ryan, because he is the only patient with no duplicate rows.

Comment: Because Chan has an orphaned record (only left eye) on '03-08-2009' and correct records on the next day visit '04-08-2009'. In other words the check should be made on a per visit basis. IMHO otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: @peterm OK, I not sure really whether this is what the OP looking for or not. Any way, he has the two answer, waiting for him to approve on of them. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

One more option with [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) operator

```
SELECT *
FROM Patients p1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM Patients p2
              WHERE p1.PatientName = p2.PatientName
              HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
              )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0de25/1) @Mahmoud Gamal thanks for the DDL Schema;)

Comment: Its OK, no need for thanks. **BTW**, you can setup the DDL schema easily, just press the **Text to DDL** button and paste the sample data there and it will create the schema automatically for you.

Comment: Wow!I didn't know about this feature.It's so simple)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  PatientName
            FROM    tablename
            GROUP   BY PatientName
            HAVING  COUNT(Eye) = 1
        ) b ON a.PatientName = b.PatientName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79c2b/2)

for faster performance, add an `INDEX` on column `PatientName`.

`COUNT(Eye)` will do best for patients that have the same recorded `eye` but on different `DateOftest`.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b8bc/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```sql
SELECT PatientName, 
       DateOftest, 
       MIN(Eye) AS Eye, 
       MIN(L1) AS L1, MIN(L2) AS L2, MIN(L3) AS L3, MIN(L4) AS L4, MIN(L5) AS L5
FROM patients
GROUP BY PatientName, DateOftest
HAVING COUNT(Eye) = 1
```

Result

```
| PATIENTNAME | DATEOFTEST | EYE | L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 | L5 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|        Chan | 03-08-2009 |   L | 18 | 21 | 28 | 35 | 12 |
|        Ryan | 18-03-2012 |   R | 12 | 18 | 27 | 39 | 40 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02a0e/5)